# Canonical livepatch = checkState: check-failed

Tags: canonical, canonical-livepatch

I have **Ubuntu 16.04.02** server with **Canonical livepatch** installed

After: **sudo canonical-livepatch status --verbose**

I have:

```
client-version: "7.21"
machine-id: 5b429XXXXXX
machine-token: 8f755XXXXXX
architecture: x86_64
cpu-model: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1245 V2 @ 3.40GHz
last-check: 2017-02-23T12:29:11.824404836Z
boot-time: 2017-02-22T15:28:43Z
uptime: 124h21m43s
status:
- kernel: 4.4.0-64.85-generic
  running: true
  livepatch:
    **checkState: check-failed**
    patchState: nothing-to-apply
    version: ""
    fixes: ""
```

**Why is that?: checkState: check-failed**

After **sudo canonical-livepatch disable [TOKEN]** and **sudo canonical-livepatch enable [TOKEN]** I have checkState: **checked**, but couple hours later again: **check-failed**

Any idea? Please advise

Comment: See this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1642581) report.